How to add an XYZ Layer with non-standard tile grid in QGIS?
When I have a TMS endpoint, like: https://tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png, I know I can add it to canvas via Layer -> Add Layer -> Add XYZ Layer.... However, this assumes that the {z}/{x}/{y} tile path is following the standard Slippy map scheme.
I have encountered geoportal.md, which offers Moldovan soil information on this page:
https://geoportal.md/en/default/map#layers=209,_base1&lat=219428.279582&lon=217509.958413&zoom=0.
The website works by loading PNGs such as https://geoportal.md/tiles/Tipulsolului/1/5/2.png:

or https://geoportal.md/tiles/Tipulsolului/3/27/13.png:

This: https://geoportal.md/tiles/Tipulsolului/ defines the:

used SRS (EPSG:4026, ie MOLDREF99)
origin of the tile grid
units-per-pixel value for each zoom level.

When using standard slippy map tiles, each tile divides up to 4 tiles in the next zoom level, so that units-per-pixel halvens at every zoom level. Unfortuntataly, this is not the case here: sometimes units-per-pixel is half of the value at the previous zoom level, sometimes it is 2.5th of the previous zoom level.
For example, at zoom level 2, units-per-pixel is 88.19439681947017106722, at zoom level 3 it is 35.27775872778806132146, and 88.19439681947017106722/35.27775872778806132146=2.5 (numbers are from here).
Based on the above, I can visualise the used tile grid by creating GeoJSONs with the borders of the tiles at different zoom levels. (The script used to create the GeoJSONs is here, but it isn't very relevant to the essence of this question.) This grid looks as follows, when zoomed in to the Eastern edge of Moldova:

Reassuringly, tile 1/5/2.png above shows shapes which conform to the red border within the 1/5/2 tile (square with thick black line, with 1/5/2 written at the centre of it).
Similarly, within 3/27/13, the country borders on the QGIS canvas appear to be very similar to the shapes on 3/27/13.png.
The squares on the QGIS canvas show that standard slippy map rules don't apply: zoom level 1 tiles split into 4 zoom level 2 tiles, but zoom level 2 tiles do not split into 4 zoom level 3 tiles (since the sidelength of a zoom level 2 tile is 2.5 times the sidelength of a zoom level 3 tile, and 2.5≠2).
I can download each tile, and knowing the coordinates of its sides, I can georeference them with gdalwarp. Doing so would enable the visualisation of these tiles in QGIS. However, I hope there is an easier way. Georeferencing tiles seems like reinventing a wheel. I would rather stick to trying to use the URL https://geoportal.md/tiles/Tipulsolului/{z}/{x}/{y}.png.
How can I visualise an XYZ Layer which uses a different tiling scheme than standard tiled web maps?

I think you are probably stuck with writing some code - the whole benefit/problem of ZXY tiles is that the assumptions of the grid are baked into the scheme from the start. Maybe you could get the data in a standard WMTS?

Thank you. I haven't yet be able to find a standard WMTS source, but if there is one it would be superior to whatever code I could write, so I hope it does exist.
